# Using static templates on ExpressionEngine with Mamp Pro

Tags: expressionengine, mamp-pro

I am trying to upload some static templates that I download from Mijingo (the site I bought a tutorial from to learn ExpressionEngine) The instructions were to upload the templates to the folder with my expressionengine files. I was then under the impression that when I opened the local site I would see the template files. I am not very experienced in this area so I appreciate any direction you can provide.

I am also willing to provide any detail needed to help diagnose this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure EE knows where your templates are located.

Sign into your control panel and navigate to:
Design -> Templates -> Global Preferences

Change the settings for `Save Templates as Files` to `Yes` and then change `Server path to site's templates` to the location of the template files you added.

Usually I would create a new folder: `/themes/site_themes/myNewTheme`, then templates will be stored in `/themes/site_themes/myNewTheme/default_site/`

After changing the settings navigate to 
Design -> Templates -> Synchronise Templates, select all the templates and click submit.

Hopefully that should do the trick :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still having a little issue. When I go to Synchronize Templates I don't see anything there. I downloaded the static templates from Mijingo (the site that I bought a tutorial from) and inside the downloaded folder are two folders that hold the templates (FPO and -). Since I am locally hosted I put the files in my ExpressionEngine folder that has my expressionengine files (/Documents/ExpressionEngine/(FPO and - are in here). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your files are stored in `/Documents/ExpressionEngine/` then there should probably be a folder `/Documents/ExpressionEngine/themes/site_themes/`, correct? Create a folder in there called `fpo` and copy the templates in there.  So in the end you should have `/Documents/ExpressionEngine/themes/site_themes/fpo/default_site/about.group` or something like that.  Make sure you set ExpressionEngine to look in the directory as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: The static templates I downloaded (from Mijingo) included two folders (FPO and -) the FPO folder has images inside of it and the - folder has `css`, `img`, and `js` folders inside of it. Should I combine these folders? Currently my Server Path on EE is `/Documents/ExpressionEngine/themes/site_themes` Inside of site_themes is `-`, `FPO`, `agile_records` (which what was already inside my site_themes folder when I installed EE) and `index.html` (which was also already there) When I go to my local site `(local.jm)` it still shows up as a blank page. **What can I do?**